# Spring Security: Custom UserDetails and GrandtedAuthority implementation

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I have configured following authentication manager and in-memory user service

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:password-encoder ref="bcrypt" />
        <security:user-service id="userService">
            <!-- 1234 -->
            <security:user name="1" password="$2a$04$68Oq1PRWyHktgJ2E4Zs9reakETagh81UGEe/QF4V1FJo9kfVBvNHq" authorities="ROLE_1" />
            <security:user name="2" password="$2a$04$68Oq1PRWyHktgJ2E4Zs9reakETagh81UGEe/QF4V1FJo9kfVBvNHq" authorities="ROLE_2" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

How do I provide custom `UserDetails` and `GrandtedAuthority` implementation for Spring to populate the `Authentication` object during authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You create a bean implementing `UserDetailsService` and wire it to the authentication-provider:

```
<bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="org.example.MyUserDetailsService"/>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
      <!-- ... -->
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

In your implementation of `UserDetailsService`, you override the `loadUserByUsername()` method.

If you don't want to create a custom user class, `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails` contains a basic `User` class. You'll notice that the constructor has an option to pass a collection of `GrantedAuthority`. A basic implementation is `org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority`.